# Cygwin 'make' command

Tags: unix, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to compile [a library](http://liblo.sourceforge.net/) using a Unix shell. I'm running Cygwin on Windows. The install instructions for the library state:

> 1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
>      ./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
>       using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type`
>      sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute`
>      configure' itself.
>
>    Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
>       messages telling which features it is checking for.
> 2. Type `make' to compile the package.
>
> <... MORE INSTRUCTIONS FOLLOW ...>

So, I've placed the folder containing the library source into my Cygwin directory, *cd*'ed to the folder, and run *./configure*. This all appears to work fine, but the 'make' command produces the following output:

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/liblo-0.26'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/liblo-0.26/src'
Making all in .
make[3]: Entering directory `/liblo-0.26/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -
Wall -I.. -g -O2 -MT liblo_la-address.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblo_la-address.Tpo
-c -o liblo_la-address.lo `test -f 'address.c' || echo './'`address.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -I.. -g -O2 -MT liblo_la-a
ddress.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/liblo_la-address.Tpo -c address.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPI
C -o .libs/liblo_la-address.o
In file included from lo_types_internal.h:33,
                 from address.c:37:
../lo/lo_osc_types.h:32:20: stdint.h: No such file or directory
In file included from address.c:37:
lo_types_internal.h:89: field `addr' has incomplete type
lo_types_internal.h:98: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
make[3]: *** [liblo_la-address.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/liblo-0.26/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/liblo-0.26/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/liblo-0.26'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Happy to provide more info - but I'm new to Unix shell (as you can probably tell...)

Comment: This isn't a shell problem. Your system is missing the standard C include file `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the header file `stdint.h` is not found.

`stdint.h` is a new header, standardized in C99 (The version published in 1999 of the C standard.) It could be that your UNIX does not have it. But cygwin should be recent and have it.

Does your cygwin installation have the C library header files installed?

Comment: His Unix isn't Unix, it's Windows (he's using Cygwin).

Comment: I've modified my question. Thanks for pointing this out. How do I find out if the header files are installed?

Comment: `find /usr/include/ -name 'stdint.h'` will search for you ... (Beware that you call the actual UNIX `find`, not the Windows one.)